# How to submit file at anytime?

Tags: jquery, blueimp, jquery-file-upload

With the Blueimp file upload plugin, there are various methods to submit file(s).
1) We can submit a file when it is added into the queue:

```
add: function (e, data) {  
   data.submit();
}
```

2) or when a button is clicked:

```
add: function (e, data) {  
   $("#submitID").on('click', function() {
   data.submit();
 })
}
```

But how to submit file at anytime, for example into an event ?

```
afterSubmit: function(response,postdata) {
  if (response.responseText == "ok") {
  *** submit***
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply click a button and trigger the upload:

```
add: function (e, data) {  
   $("#submitID").on('click', function() {
   data.submit();
 })
}

afterSubmit: function(response,postdata) {
  if (response.responseText == "ok") {
      $("#submitID").click();
  }
}
```

Other way would be to use variable to save the file there and submit it whenever you want:

```
var file;
...
add: function (e, data) {  
      file=data;  
    }
....
....
if (response.responseText == "ok") {
      file.submit();
}
```

Comment: And if the button doesn't exists ?!

Comment: I don't know if your proposition is compatible with the plugin. I must test it unless you did it.

Comment: Yes ! simple solution but I didn't think to it ! Thank you